# Reshape a 3D matrix

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python. How can I reshape 356x356x356 image to 3xN? 
The code below did not worked:

a = np.reshape(data, (1, 356*356*356), 'F')
   b=np.reshape(b, (3, 15039338), 'F')

Thanks